# How to develop interactive graph using Gephi Toolkit?

Tags: graph, preview, interactive, gephi

I'm trying to use [Gephi Toolkit](http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Toolkit_portal) to create a graph Applet and intergrate it into our JavaEE web site. But the problem is Gephi Toolkit (the Preview API) has nearly no interactive features supported.

According to [this topic](http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=2473&p=8179&hilit=preview+interactive#p8179) on Gephi forum, one should implement a mouse listener to handle mouse event such as clicking on a node. However, I didn't figure it out... Can anyone help me on this?

Code:
I create a class to show a random graph (no problem for this), and then I add a new class who implements **PreviewMouseListener** and just print a msg when a node is clicked.

```
    /*
    Copyright 2008-2010 Gephi
    Authors : Mathieu Bastian <mathieu.bastian@gephi.org>
    Website : http://www.gephi.org

    This file is part of Gephi.

    Gephi is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as
    published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the
    License, or (at your option) any later version.

    Gephi is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU Affero General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
    along with Gephi.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
     */

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.io.File;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    import org.gephi.graph.api.GraphController;
    import org.gephi.graph.api.GraphModel;
    import org.gephi.graph.api.NodeIterator;
    import org.gephi.io.generator.plugin.RandomGraph;
    import org.gephi.io.importer.api.Container;
    import org.gephi.io.importer.api.ContainerFactory;
    import org.gephi.io.importer.api.ImportController;
    import org.gephi.io.processor.plugin.DefaultProcessor;
    import org.gephi.layout.plugin.random.Random;
    import org.gephi.layout.plugin.random.RandomLayout;
    import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewController;
    import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewModel;
    import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewProperty;
    import org.gephi.preview.api.ProcessingTarget;
    import org.gephi.preview.api.RenderTarget;
    import org.gephi.preview.types.DependantOriginalColor;
    import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController;
    import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
    import org.openide.util.Lookup;

    import processing.core.PApplet;

    /**
     *
     * @author Mathieu Bastian
     */
    public class PreviewJFrame {

        public void script() {
            //Init a project - and therefore a workspace
            ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
            pc.newProject();
            Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

            //Generate a random graph
            Container container = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ContainerFactory.class).newContainer();
            RandomGraph randomGraph = new RandomGraph();
            randomGraph.setNumberOfNodes(50);
            randomGraph.setWiringProbability(0.005);
            randomGraph.generate(container.getLoader());

            //Append imported data to GraphAPI
            ImportController importController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ImportController.class);
            importController.process(container, new DefaultProcessor(), workspace);
            GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(GraphController.class).getModel();

            //Preview configuration
            PreviewController previewController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PreviewController.class);
            PreviewModel previewModel = previewController.getModel();
            previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.SHOW_NODE_LABELS, Boolean.TRUE);
            previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.NODE_LABEL_COLOR, new DependantOriginalColor(Color.WHITE));
            previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_CURVED, Boolean.TRUE);
            previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_OPACITY, 50);
            previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_RADIUS, 10f);
            previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.BLACK);
            previewController.refreshPreview();

            //New Processing target, get the PApplet
            ProcessingTarget target = (ProcessingTarget) previewController.
                    getRenderTarget(RenderTarget.PROCESSING_TARGET);
            PApplet applet = target.getApplet();
            applet.init();

            //Refresh the preview and reset the zoom
            previewController.render(target);
              RandomLayout layout = new RandomLayout(new Random(),1500);
              layout.setGraphModel(graphModel);
              layout.initAlgo();
              layout.goAlgo();
              layout.endAlgo();
              //Add the applet to a JFrame and display--------------------------------------
              JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Preview");
              frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

              frame.pack();
              frame.setVisible(true);
              target.refresh();
              target.resetZoom();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PreviewJFrame previewJFrame = new PreviewJFrame();
            previewJFrame.script();
        }
    }
```

MouseListener:

```
    import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewMouseEvent;
    import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewProperties;
    import org.gephi.preview.spi.MouseResponsiveRenderer;
    import org.gephi.preview.spi.PreviewMouseListener;
    import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
    import org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider;

    @ServiceProvider(service = PreviewMouseListener.class)
    public class AtosPreviewMouseListener implements PreviewMouseListener{
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(PreviewMouseEvent event,
                PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {
            System.out.println("I'm clicked!!");
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(PreviewMouseEvent event,
                PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(PreviewMouseEvent event,
                PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {}
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(PreviewMouseEvent event,
                PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {}
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

PS: I've tried to reply that topic, but my account is not activated yet even thought I registered many days ago...

Answer (score 2):

I played with gephi for a few days and I'm pretty sure there's no way to get the exact node clicked.  It really doesn't seem that their API was built with interactivity in mind.  However I've found that this works relatively well for a 2D graph.

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.gephi.graph.api.*;
import org.gephi.io.processor.plugin.DefaultProcessor;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewController;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewModel;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewProperty;
import org.gephi.preview.api.ProcessingTarget;
import org.gephi.preview.api.RenderTarget;
import org.gephi.preview.types.DependantOriginalColor;
import org.gephi.project.api.ProjectController;
import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
import org.openide.util.Lookup;
import processing.core.PApplet;

/**
 * This demo shows basic features from GraphAPI, how to create and query a graph
 * programmatically.
 * 
 * @author Mathieu Bastian
 */
public class TestGraph {


public void script() {
    //Init a project - and therefore a workspace
    ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
    pc.newProject();
    Workspace workspace = pc.getCurrentWorkspace();

    //Get a graph model - it exists because we have a workspace
    GraphModel graphModel = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(GraphController.class).getModel();

    //Create three nodes
    Node n0 = graphModel.factory().newNode("n0");
    n0.getNodeData().setLabel("Node 0");
    Node n1 = graphModel.factory().newNode("n1");
    n1.getNodeData().setLabel("Node 1");
    Node n2 = graphModel.factory().newNode("n2");
    n2.getNodeData().setLabel("Node 2");

    //Create three edges
    Edge e1 = graphModel.factory().newEdge(n1, n2, 1f, true);
    Edge e2 = graphModel.factory().newEdge(n0, n2, 2f, true);
    Edge e3 = graphModel.factory().newEdge(n2, n0, 2f, true);   //This is e2's mutual edge

    //Append as a Directed Graph
    DirectedGraph directedGraph = graphModel.getDirectedGraph();
    directedGraph.addNode(n0);
    directedGraph.addNode(n1);
    directedGraph.addNode(n2);
    directedGraph.addEdge(e1);
    directedGraph.addEdge(e2);
    directedGraph.addEdge(e3);

    //Count nodes and edges
    System.out.println("Nodes: "+directedGraph.getNodeCount()+" Edges: "+directedGraph.getEdgeCount());

    //Get a UndirectedGraph now and count edges
    UndirectedGraph undirectedGraph = graphModel.getUndirectedGraph();
    GraphView view = undirectedGraph.getView();

    System.out.println("Edges: "+undirectedGraph.getEdgeCount());   //The mutual edge is automatically merged

    //Iterate over nodes
    for(Node n : directedGraph.getNodes()) {
        Node[] neighbors = directedGraph.getNeighbors(n).toArray();
        System.out.println(n.getNodeData().getLabel()+" has "+neighbors.length+" neighbors");
    }

    //Iterate over edges
    for(Edge e : directedGraph.getEdges()) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource().getNodeData().getId()+" -> "+e.getTarget().getNodeData().getId());
    }

    //Find node by id
    Node node2 = directedGraph.getNode("n2");

    //Get degree
    System.out.println("Node2 degree: "+directedGraph.getDegree(node2));

    //Preview configuration
    PreviewController previewController = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PreviewController.class);
    PreviewModel previewModel = previewController.getModel();

    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.SHOW_NODE_LABELS, Boolean.FALSE);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.NODE_LABEL_COLOR, new DependantOriginalColor(Color.WHITE));
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_CURVED, Boolean.FALSE);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_OPACITY, 50);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.EDGE_RADIUS, 10f);
    previewModel.getProperties().putValue(PreviewProperty.BACKGROUND_COLOR, Color.BLACK);
    previewController.refreshPreview();

    //New Processing target, get the PApplet
    ProcessingTarget target = (ProcessingTarget) previewController.getRenderTarget(RenderTarget.PROCESSING_TARGET);
    PApplet applet = target.getApplet();
    applet.init();
    //Refresh the preview and reset the zoom
    previewController.render(target);
    target.refresh();
    target.resetZoom();

    //Add the applet to a JFrame and display
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Preview");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestGraph previewJFrame = new TestGraph();
    previewJFrame.script();
}
}
```

Mouse Listener substitute:

```
import org.gephi.graph.api.Graph;
import org.gephi.graph.api.GraphModel;
import org.gephi.graph.api.Node;
import org.gephi.graph.api.NodeData;
import org.gephi.graph.api.NodeIterable;
import org.gephi.graph.api.NodeIterator;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewModel;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewMouseEvent;
import org.gephi.preview.api.PreviewProperties;
import org.gephi.preview.spi.PreviewMouseListener;
import org.gephi.project.api.Workspace;
import org.openide.util.Lookup;
import org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider;

/**
 *
 * @author ksexton
 */
@ServiceProvider(service = PreviewMouseListener.class)
public class MyMouseListener implements PreviewMouseListener {

public void mouseClicked(PreviewMouseEvent event, PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {
    System.out.println("(" + event.x + "," + event.y + ")");
    Lookup lookup = workspace.getLookup();
    GraphModel lookup1 = lookup.lookup(GraphModel.class);
    Graph graph = lookup1.getGraph();
    NodeIterable nodes = graph.getNodes();
    NodeIterator iterator = nodes.iterator();
    Node selectedNode = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Node next = iterator.next();
        NodeData nodeData = next.getNodeData();
        float x = nodeData.x();
        float y = -nodeData.y(); // event y is always wrong.
        float z = nodeData.z();
        float size = nodeData.getSize();
        final int minX = Math.round(x - size);
        final int maxX = Math.round(x + size);
        final int minY = Math.round(y - size);
        final int maxY = Math.round(y + size);
        System.out.println("(" + minX + "," + minY+")" + ", (" + maxX + "," + maxY+")");
        if (minX <= event.x && event.x <= maxX
                && minY <= event.y && event.y <= maxY) {
            selectedNode = next;
        }
    }
    if (selectedNode != null) {
        System.out.println("Found a Node!: (" + selectedNode.getNodeData().x()
                + "," + selectedNode.getNodeData().y() + ")");
    }
}

public void mousePressed(PreviewMouseEvent event, PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {
}

public void mouseDragged(PreviewMouseEvent event, PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {
}

public void mouseReleased(PreviewMouseEvent event, PreviewProperties properties, Workspace workspace) {
}
}
```

Renderer:

```
import org.gephi.preview.plugin.renderers.NodeRenderer;
import org.gephi.preview.spi.MouseResponsiveRenderer;
import org.gephi.preview.spi.PreviewMouseListener;
import org.gephi.preview.spi.Renderer;
import org.openide.util.lookup.ServiceProvider;

/**
 *
 * @author ksexton
 */
@ServiceProvider(service = Renderer.class)
public class NodeRenderer2 extends NodeRenderer implements MouseResponsiveRenderer {

public boolean needsPreviewMouseListener(PreviewMouseListener previewMouseListener) {
    return true;
}

}
```

If anyone has a better, less error prone way I'd like to know.

Comment: They refer in this tutorial to some node click events. https://gephi.org/tutorials/gephi-tutorial-visualization.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you need a render to use the PreviewMouseListener.
I think this topic will help you a lot. And the top comes from the Gephi Forum.
Do not forget to implement the MouseReseponsiveRenderer to your Renderer.
Draw your painting in the render method.